# Created singleton object can't be detected in main function (Scala)

Tags: package, singleton, program-entry-point

Singleton object LongLines which I created can't be recognized in object with main function (FindingLines). I put their files (LongLines.scala, FindingLines.scala ) in /src/main/scala/com/files/lines directory. Program code should have to find in particular file the lines which length is greater than parameter *width*.

Codes:

1) LongLines.scala (version from book I learn):

```
package com.files.lines
import scala.io.Source

object LongLines {

    def processFile(filename: String, width: Int) {
      val source = Source.fromFile(filename)
      for (line <- source.getLines())
      processLine(filename, width, line)
    }

    private def processLine(filename: String,
      width: Int, line: String) {
      if (line.length > width)
      println(filename +": "+ line.trim)
    }
}
```

2) LongLines.scala (my own version):

```
package com.files.lines
import scala.io.Source._
import java.nio.files.Paths._

object LongLines {

   def processFile(filePath: String, width:Int): Unit = {
      val path = get(filePath)
      val fileName = path.getFileName.toString
      val lines = fromFile(filePath).getLines().toList
      for (line<-lines) processLines(fileName,line,width)
   }

   private def processLines(fileName: String, line: String, width: Int): Unit = {
      if (line.length() > width) println(s"$fileName: $line");
   } 
}
```

3) FindingLines.scala (book version I used - only version):

```
package com.files.lines    

object FindLongLines {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val width = args(0).toInt
    for (arg <- args.drop(1))
        LongLines.processFile(arg, width)
 }
```

}

---

Error (compiled from linux terminal):

After I compiled program with my version and book version of LongLines.scala (separately, of course):

```
  scalac FindingLines.scala
```

I've got this error:

```
FindLongLines.scala:15: error: not found: value LongLines
        LongLines.processFile(arg, width)
        ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
1) I removed "package com.file.lines" from both files (FindingLines.scala, LongLines.scala) - that means I need not to remove those files in this package (directory). Those two files could stay in src/main/scala directory.
2) scalac FindingLines.scala LongLines.scala
3) scala FindingLines.scala 45 ~/workspace/Rational/src/Rational.scala
```